# No connection to local NAS after upgrade from 18.04 to 22.04

Tags: networking, mount, 22.04, kubuntu, nas

Dear AskUbuntu users,

I recently upgraded my Kubuntu 18.04 to 20.04 and then 22.04.

My mounting script for my NAS WD Mycloud stopped working. I investigated and here are my findings:

- I can ping the NAS.
- I cannot access the web interface with any web
  browser (firefox / chromium).
- I cannot mount it (cifs).
- I cannot connect on ssh to it. (ssh: connect to host ###.###.###.### port ##: Connection refused)
- I cannot connect to it via samba using dolphin "the file or folder does not exist".

The NAS is still working fine and is accessible on LAN by other computers. All the above was working just fine before the upgrade.

Not being able to access even the web interface, makes me believe that the issues with mounting and ssh access are due to networking issues.

I disabled the firewall and I am not using any proxies. No improvement.

Any ideas?

Comment: Please [edit your question](https://askubuntu.com/posts/1494020/edit) to show us the complete output an ssh connection attempt. Failed attempts return specific reasons. "Cannot connect" is not among those reasons, which suggests that you have inadvertently discarded vital troubleshooting information. So let's go back and obtain it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have an access point connected to the router. This was assigning my computer a different IP after the upgrade, which happened to be the same as the NAS. However the NAS is connected to the router directly, so I could access the NAS perfectly from other devices, and my AP assigned IP was not conflicting with the router rules for some reason.

After reassigning the static IPs I used to have, everything works again.

So no samba issues, no ssh issues... just needed to check the static IPs after the upgrade.

Comment: Thanks for letting us know the result of your troubleshooting!